# What's the syntax for using += with a variable when using the .animate function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to animate the right margin of an element using += to continually add to the margin each time the function is called. I want the value to be a variable though and I can't figure out the syntax.

Here's what I have:

```
$('.wide')animate({"right" : '+=320px'}, scrollSpeed, scrollEase);
```

And that works but here's what I'm trying to do:

```
$('.wide').animate({"right" : +=variable}, scrollSpeed, scrollEase);
```

I'm not sure what the correct syntax is though.

Thans for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`$('.wide').animate({"right" : '+=' + variable + 'px'}, scrollSpeed, scrollEase);`

Just concatenate a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just use the `+` operator.

`'+=' + variable` should work out, though it may not depending on what `variable` actually IS .

Make sure it's consistent when fully evaluated with the working literal one.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery interprets arguments like this as a string, so you can just concatenate the string. Also, you can omit the "px" for terseness sake. jQuery will figure that out for you.

```
$('.wide').animate({'right' : '+=' + variable}, scrollSpeed, scrollEase);
```